# How to use the <label> tag in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, html, usability, label

How can I use the `<label>` tag within an ASP.NET application? I want it to be valid, accessible, and usable.

I understand the optimal HTML way is this:

```
<label for="Username">Username:</label>
<input type="text" id="Username" runat="server" />
```

But if the above code is in an ASP.NET user control, the input ID will change, meaning the label's "for" attribute is useless. I could make the label tag a server control and set its "for" attribute in the code (`Username.ClientID`), but it seems like a lot of work for such a simple thing.

I've also seen this HTML used in the past:

```
<label>
    <span>Username</span>
    <input type="text" id="Username" runat="server" />
</label>
```

What is the proper approach?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I use `<asp:Label ... AssociatedControlID="Username" ...>` controls for this.  They get rendered as `<label>` tags and set the `for` attribute appropriately.

Note that you can also nest other tags within the Label control if you wish:

```
<asp:Label ID="UsernameLabel"
           Text="Username:"
           AssociatedControlID="UsernameTextBox"
           runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="UsernameTextBox" runat="server" />
</asp:Label>
```

Comment: I too use this approach but always set EnableViewState="False" for the label tag, particularly if it is a substantial form. The smaller the viewstate the better in my opinion.

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113479/when-to-enable-disable-viewstate

Comment: Agreed.  It was left out for brevity.

Comment: I find it easier to turn ViewState off in Web.Config page settings and turn it on on only the controls you need it for. Yes, ViewState really adds up and slow things down if you just leave it on for all controls.

Comment: You want to be careful as well. It may be that you want a <label> tag and the asp:Label controller will in fact render a <span>

Comment: If the asp:Label control has an AssociatedControlID, it will correctly render a <label>, not its usual <span>.

Comment: This is what we do but I've just found out it breaks if you change the labels text in anyway. eg `UsernameLabe.Text = "some error message"` will cause the TextBox control to disappear and it will throw an HttpException because it can't find the associated control.

Comment: Does it make a difference to nest other tags within the Label control?

Answer (score 18):

You can also write it like this:

```
<label for="<%= Username.ClientID %>">Username:</label>
<asp:TextBox ID="Username" runat="server" />
```

Phil Haack has a [blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/02/15/asp.net_tip_-_use_the_label_control_correctly.aspx) on this topic

Comment: OP says in the question that they already know they can do this.

Answer (score 10):

use the `<asp:Label>` server control.  It has a property that you can use to set the associated control ID.

```
<asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server" Text="Username" AssociatedControlID="Text1" />
<asp:TextBox ID="Text1" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 7):

I guess the easiest way to do it is this.

```
<asp:Label AssociatedControlID="Username" runat="server" Text="Username:"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="Username" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want a label, but don't have another control to use in `AssociatedControlID` one can use the label itself

```
<asp:Label ID="Not_Span" AssociatedControlID="Not_Span" Text="Will be rendered as label" />
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using .NET 4 you can now use the ClientIDMode property to configure one or more controls to use static or predictable ID's. The ClientIDMode property can be set on the TextBox directly or you can set it on any parent control or the containing page.

```
<label for="Username">Username:</label>
<asp:TextBox ID="Username" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Read more about the ClientIDMode on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

```
<p><asp:Label ID="label1"           Text="Username:"           AssociatedControlID="txtUserName"           runat="server">    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" /></asp:Label></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

You my also try and this:

```
<asp:Label  ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="label"></asp:Label>
```

This is what Visual Studio, or any other software gives you if you drag and drop a label.