# How to use label for in an ASP.Net webform?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, label

I get this as pure HTML:

```
<label for="txtPais">Pais:</label>    
<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtPais" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtPais" class="textInput" />
```

In my actual code in Visual Studio I have this:

```
<label for="txtPais">Pais:</label>    
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPais" runat="server" CssClass="textInput"></asp:TextBox>
```

How would I apply a label for this textbox?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493801/html-label-tag-and-asp-net

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You should use the `<asp:Label...>` as detailed in [this blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/02/15/asp.net_tip_-_use_the_label_control_correctly.aspx) on Haacked

```
<asp:Label id="label" AssociatedControlId="txtPais" Text="Pais:" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox id="txtPais" runat="server" CssClass="textInput" />
```

This should convert correctly with the ID being converted.

Answer (score -1):

It is recommended to wrap some inputs inside of labels for accessibility (See this [example](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/47920)).

```
<asp:Label ID="UsernameLabel"
           Text="Username:"
           AssociatedControlID="UsernameTextBox"
           runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="UsernameTextBox" runat="server" />
</asp:Label>
```

I got this answer from the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/493806) that, as it happens is mentioned in a comment in the original question.