# ASP.NET matching id on label and input pairs

Tags: asp.net, input, label

Is have about 20 label/input pairs on a page that use JS to give them unique styling. For this to work they must have matching id's on each pair.

This is the way the I would like the HTML to be formatted:

```
<p class="radioBtn">
    <label for="business00"></label>
    <input id="business00" type="radio" name="radioBtn" value="" />
</p>
<p class="radioBtn">    
    <label for="private00"></label>
    <input id="private00" type="radio" name="radioBtn" value="" />
</p>
<p class="radioBtn">
    <label for="business01"></label>
    <input id="business01" type="radio" name="radioBtn" value="" />
</p>
<p class="radioBtn">    
    <label for="private01"></label>
    <input id="private01" type="radio" name="radioBtn" value="" />
</p>
```

and so on.

Can this be achieved using ASP.NET? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Html label tag and ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493801/html-label-tag-and-asp-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493801/html-label-tag-and-asp-net) will answer your question.

Comment: Basically, just use "AssociatedControlID"

<asp:Label ... AssociatedControlID="Username" ...>