# Is there any control in ASP.NET Web Forms, which is rendered in <label> html tag?

Tags: html, asp.net, webforms, label

Is there any control in ASP.NET Web Forms, which is rendered in  html tag on page rendering?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Html label tag and ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493801/html-label-tag-and-asp-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `Label` control and the `AssociatedControlId` property.

```
<asp:Label id="lLabel" AssociatedControlId="tbMyField" Text="My field" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox id="tbMyField" runat="server" Text="My field" />
```

This will render as

```
<label for="tbMyField">My field</label>
<input type="tbMyField" name="tbMyField" value="My field" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with creating  user control which contains property "Text" in code-behind and markup `<label><%= Text %></label>`

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Konstantin Zadiran's answer, in the html:

```
<label id="lblLabel"><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litLabelText"></asp:Literal></label>
```

and in the code behind:

```
litLabelText.Text = ...
```